# Display a warning when dropping a component on a form at design time

Tags: delphi, components

I'm tidying up components used in a large legacy project, I've eliminated about 90 of 220 custom components, replacing them with standard Delphi controls.  Some of the remaining components require a significant amount work to remove which I don't have available.  I would like to prevent anyone from making additional use of some of these components and was wondering if there was a way of showing a message if the component is dropped on the form at design time - something like "Don't use this control, use x or y instead".

Another possibility would to hide the control on the component pallet (but still have the control correctly render on the form at design time).

Comment: Going to be easiest to tell people not to use them. Sounds rather old school, but that's my considered opinion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will certainly do this, but would be nice to avoid this discussion for every new hire or contractor that works on the code.

Comment: You just let people go at the code without any introduction or training?

Comment: You can inherit your forms from a common base form, and then detect when a component is added to it and put your prompt there. It's that detecting part which I'm not entirely sure of, but I believe there is a way.

Comment: One possible way is when the controls are installed into the tool palette, have the registration unit move the obsolete controls into its own tool palette category and have it named something like "My Controls (obsolete)" That way anyone looking at the tool palette will notice the caption says obsolete.

Comment: Better yet, in the constructor of each of such components, simply add `MessageDlg('Do not use this!', mtError, [mbOK], 0);` (of course first checking if you're in design-time).

Comment: @JerryDodge This is what I want to achieve, except only when it is being dropped onto a Form.  I don't want this message to appear every time a developer opens the form - or worse yet the end user seeing the message.

Comment: True, actually Craig's advise seems your best route of action.

Comment: @Craig Yes, I've done this for a few controls, this might be a sensible option for the rest of them.  I've also renamed a few of the controls to make it a bit clearer that they have specific purposes and not for general use.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the lack of training / induction may go somewhere to explaining the current state of the code - some of which is now 20 years old.  There have been many different developers work on the code base over that time, and many custom controls introduced.  Many don't support Unicode, which is going to be an issue moving forward.

Comment: AFAIK, the documented way to register a component without adding it to the tool palette is `RegisterNoIcon`.

Comment: Thanks @UweRaabe, I've also just noticed this one - will probably make use of this.

Comment: I've updated my answer, might be useful at last.

Answer (score 17):

There is protected dynamic method [TComponent.PaletteCreated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TComponent.PaletteCreated), which is called only in one case: when we add this component to a form from component palette.

> Responds when the component is created from the component palette.
>
> PaletteCreated is called automatically at design time when the component has just been created from the component palette. Component writers can override this method to perform adjustments that are required only when the component is created from the component palette.
>
> As implemented in TComponent, PaletteCreated does nothing.

You can override this method to show warning, so it will alert the user just one time, when he tries to put it to form.

**UPDATE**

I couldn't make this procedure work in Delphi 7, XE2 and Delphi 10 Seattle (trial version), so it seems that call to PaletteCreated from IDE is not implemented.

I sent report to QC:http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=135152
maybe developers will make it work some day.

**UPDATE 2**

There are some funny workarounds, I've tried them all this time, works normally. Suppose that TOldBadButton is one of components that shouldn't be used. We override 'Loaded' procedure and WMPaint message handler:

```
TOldBadButton=class(TButton)
private
  fNoNeedToShowWarning: Boolean; //false when created
  //some other stuff
protected
  procedure Loaded; override;
  procedure WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint); message WM_PAINT;
  //some other stuff
end;
```

and implementation:

```
procedure TBadOldButton.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  fNoNeedToShowWarning:=true;
end;

procedure TOldBadButton.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPAINT);
begin
  inherited;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and not fNoNeedToShowWarning then begin
    Application.MessageBox('Please, don''t use this component','OldBadButton');
    fNoNeedToShowWarning:=true;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is, this works only for visual components. If you have custom dialogs, imagelists etc, they never get WMPaint message. In that case we can add another property, so when it is shown in object inspector, it calls getter and here we display warning. Something like this:

```
  TStupidOpenDialog = class(TOpenDialog)
  private
    fNoNeedToShowWarning: boolean;
    function GetAawPlease: string;
    procedure SetAawPlease(value: string);
    //some other stuff
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
    //some other stuff
  published
    //with name like this, probably will be on top in property list
    property Aaw_please: string read GetAawPlease write SetAawPlease;
  end;
```

implementation:

```
procedure TStupidOpenDialog.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  fNoNeedToShowWarning:=true; //won't show warning when loading form
end;

procedure TStupidOpenDialog.SetAawPlease(value: string);
begin
//nothing, we need this empty setter, otherwise property won't appear on object
//inspector
end;

function TStupidOpenDialog.GetAawPlease: string;
begin
  Result:='Don''t use this component!';
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and not fNoNeedToShowWarning then begin
    Application.MessageBox('Please, don''t use this component','StupidOpenDialog');
    fNoNeedToShowWarning:=true;
  end;
end;
```

Older versions of Delphi always scroll object inspector to the top when new component is added from palette, so our Aaw_please property will surely work. Newer versions tend to start with some chosen place in property list, but non-visual components usually have quite a few properties, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Interesting, in all my years using and writing VCL components, I have never seen or heard of `PaletteCreated()`.

Comment: First time hearing about this. Awesome

Comment: @Alister I'm wondering why you have not accepted this answer (or indeed any other answers in recent times). Since this is clearly such a perfect answer to your question I can only assume that you've forgotten about the etiquette of accepting answers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan While the solution looks fairly straight forward, I've not actually been able to get it to work.  The component constructor is called when it is dropped on the form but PaletteCreated doesn't seem to be.  My test code looks good, the package gets reinstalled into the IDE just fine, but PaletteCreated does not fire.  Maybe I'm doing something wrong as I'm surprised so many people would up-vote this answer if it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidHeffeman, Alister, sorry guys, I couldn't make it work either. Seems that calling PalleteCreated form IDE isn't implemented in any of Delphi versions. Didn't expect that, delphi documentation never failed me before. I think, that could count as a bug and sent QC report, also see in update some workarounds, they work (checked in several versions), but they are not so elegant unfortunately.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 0):

To determine when the component is first created (dropped on the form)?

Override **"CreateWnd"** and use the following if statement in it:

```
if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
  // We have first create
```

More detail here >>
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031209/how-to-tell-if-an-object-is-created-from-streaming-or-not/70749790#70749790)