# How to tell if an object is created from Streaming or not

Tags: delphi

I have two separate requirements to detect if an object is being created from a stream while in the Create / AfterConstruction code.

In the first case I have an existing object which is being refeactored so it is implemented as a component to allow consuming users to drop the component on a form or data module.  One of the properties of this component is a Uuid which needs to be assigned uniquely to each object instance, and needs to remain unique for that object instance across different runs of the program.  Internally the Uuid is held in our own class but we present a UuidString property to the user in the IDE.  I need to know whether to allocate a Uuid and register the component on first creation, or wait until the Loaded routine (which is never called if it's not read from a stream).

In the second case I have a set of components that provide an 'OnReady' event to the application.  Once the object is completely initialised (which could be asynchronous) the event is called.  If the object is being streamed then I can override Loaded method to undertake additional configuiration, but if it's not being streamed Loaded will never be called and I should start the additional work in AfterConstruction.

Looking at the documentation I though I could use:

```pascal
  if( not (csLoading in Self.ComponentState) ) then
    ...
```

Or, to catch newly created objects in the designer specifically:

```pascal
if( (csDesigning in Self.ComponentState) And
    not (csLoading in Self.ComponentState) ) then
  ...
```

However having looked into the Code (I'm not really a Delphi programmer by background) I see that csLoading is only set *after* the Create / AfterConstruction has executed.

During Create / AfterConstruction execution is there anyway I can tell if Loaded is going to be called?

I have realised that *all* components created by streaming will have `Owner<>nil` but it's expected that components created at runtime would normally have `Owner<>nil` as well.

My only thought at the moment is to see if the owner is loading with something like:

```pascal
  if( (Self.Owner<>nil) And (not (csLoading in Self.Owner.ComponentState)) ) then
    ...
```

Is this the correct approach?  Or is there a better 'Delphi Way' to do it?

Comment: Why not create flag `UuidGenerated` and set it to `True` during `Loaded` or `AfterConstruction` methods? Then if you either work in IDE or in run-time, unique value will be generated automatically by one of appropriate methods.

Comment: @Dima, Thanks for the suggestion.  I can of course check if I have run the initialisation code - the problem is I don't want to complete initialisation until after I have streamed properties in, but in AfterConstruction csLoading is not set in ComponentState so I don't know if Loaded will be called...

Comment: Method `Loaded` called when you open form in IDE and when loading program in run-time. When this method is called, it means that component has correct values that had been loaded. `AfterConstruction` method called after last constructor executed. In that case not all properties of component could be correctly loaded at moment of method call. According to this, I would rely on `Loaded` method. Since `Loaded` method is not called for dynamic created components, I would use `AfterConstruction` method, checking inside for `not csDesigning`. Never call `Loaded` explicitly, as IDE does it itself.

Comment: @Dima - You understand the problem - Loaded is only called if the component is streamed.  If created at runtime or if a new component in the designer then Loaded is not called (as the object isn't loaded from a stream).  AfterConstruction is, but csLoading is never set in ComponentState until after AfterConstruction has completed.  So if Loaded is called it is the correct place to run our initialisation, but if it's not going to be called we need to call from AfterConstruction instead.  So my question is about knowing (with certainty) whether or not Loaded will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your property is named `UUIDString` backed by a field `FUUIDString`. Then this approach should work:

```
type
  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FUUIDString: string;
    function GetUUIDString: string;
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
  public
    property UUIDString: string read GetUUIDString write FUUIDString;
  end;

function TMyComponent.GetUUIDString: string;
begin
  if FUUIDString = '' then
    FUUIDString := CreateNewUUIDString;
  Result := FUUIDString;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  RegisterUUIDString(UUIDString);
end;
```

If `UUIDString` is loaded during the stream reading it will contain the stored value. Otherwise the register call inside Loaded will generate a new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - My question is about knowing whether or not Loaded will be called.  I understand your code and in some cases it's a good fit - create property values when they are required, but in my case I need to run initialisation code and not just assign a single value.  Does my suggestion at the bottom of the question work reliably?

Comment: "Does my suggestion at the bottom of the question work reliably?" No. Components do not necessarily have owners. My suggestion is that you stop trying to find a way to adapt the existing design which seems flawed, and determine the best way to solve the underlying problem, and then implement that.

Comment: @David - thanks for the comment. I understand that components do not necessarily have owners (hence testing for Owner<>nil). Is it possible for the streaming system to create a component without an owner - I don't think so, but I don't have that much experience in Delphi. If we're not created by the streaming system then Loaded won't be called, but we can have an owner and not be streamed, hence the test on the Owner ... does that test work reliably? I respect your opinion re the design but as I have given minimum information to describe the problem it's a bold suggestion for you to make.

Comment: @Rob You asked "Or is there a better 'Delphi Way' to do it?" And you are right, you haven't given us the full picture, so it's wrong for us to comment. I will therefore take your advice and say no more.

Comment: In case loaded is not always called in your environment, you can as well move the RegisterUUISString call to AfterConstruction, which is also called after Loaded in the streaming case. The idea is to delay the creation of a new UUID to allow an existing one to be read from the stream first. You just have to make sure that the Getter is called after any streaming has finished.

Comment: @Uwe AfterConstruction is called *before* loading properties when streaming (and therefore before Loaded gets called), and before csLoading is set in ComponentState (so I can't check that to see if Loaded *will* be called).  Hence my question - how do I know if Loaded will be called?

Comment: You probably cannot inside the Create sequence. Seems you should give Davids suggestion about re-design a second thought.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close to a solution. You just needed to override the correct procedure.

**I’m using "CreateWnd" for the following reasons:**

1. I need to initialise images that require the parent (Panel) to have a Handle ready, so this procedure is the right place to do that.
2. It is called when ComponentState is established (with csDesigning and/or csLoading).
3. Any Published Property is available (has been streamed in from the DFM) at this point.
4. It is only called once.

The component I’m working on is a “Picture- Button”, made form a TCustomPanel with a TSpeedButton on it and up to 4 images also on the panel.
So I wanted to put initial (default) images on the panel, which requires determining when the component is first created (dropped on the form).
See some of the code below >>

```
………
protected
  { Protected declarations }
  procedure CreateWnd; override;
  procedure DoInitialConfig;
………

procedure TJEPicButton.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and not (csLoading in ComponentState) then
  begin   // Initial State Only
    DoInitialConfig;
  end;
  // More code here....
 end;

procedure TJEPicButton.DoInitialConfig;
begin
  // Load initial (default) image(s) on panel
  // The user can (using Object Inspector) replace this image(s) with his own…
end;
```

Comment: Johan - Thanks for this, it's a great answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work for `TComponent` descendents, only for `TWinControl` descendents (i.e. controls that have a Window handle).  In my use case it doesn't really help me.  Hardly any of my components descend from TWinControl - where I do have visual components they're usually designed to render onto a canvas provided by the application which minimises the number of HWNDs in use (which looking at WinSpy seems to be what most performant UI programs do).  But I can see that for a `TWinControl` descendent this is a great approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Rob.
Yes, that does make sense. Pity it did not help you with your application.
All the components I’ve written so far are descendant from TWinControl, so they are indeed a bit different to your ones.